Question about programming behavioral experiments
Looking to program a behavioral experiment where two people interact via writing done on digitizer pads (like Wacom pads) in real-time. What language would cogsci/compsci people recommend for this? Have done some experimental design in jspsych and psychopy but this seems to require something different. Any ideas?
The experiments will take place in the same room, though the two participants will not be able to see each other's screen. The task is to use digitized handwriting to convey basic information for a joint problem solving task.
